# C# Position Question

Tags: c#

Ive got this following code in VB, want to use it into c# and I thought I had it right but when I click the event it only takes me to record #2, I have several records in my table.

```
private void pictureBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sF1411BindingSource.Position = +1;
}
```

Same for when I hit back. If I'm on record 12 for example, I click the event and bam to the 1st record. I'm a Vb guy and I'm trying to teach myself c# here so maybe I'm over looking something.

```
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sF1411BindingSource.Position = -1;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you want to do += and -=:

```
private void pictureBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sF1411BindingSource.Position += 1;
}
```

and

```
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sF1411BindingSource.Position -= 1;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

+= and -= for incrementing and decrementing is the same in C# and VB.

```
sF1411BindingSource.Position += 1; 

sF1411BindingSource.Position -= 1;
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to increment the value, use +=:   `Position += 1;`

Answer (score 1):

You should use Position += 1; instead

```
Private void pictureBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { sF1411BindingSource.Position += 1; }


private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { sF1411BindingSource.Position -= 1; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you mean:

```
private void pictureBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sF1411BindingSource.Position +=1;
}
```

?

Answer (score 1):

Is your intent that the method pictureBox2_Click will add 1 to sF1411BindingSource.Position ? If that's the case you need to use the [+= operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa7629ew.aspx).  Use the [-= operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2y9zhhx1.aspx) to decrement by 1.

```
private void pictureBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     sF1411BindingSource.Position += 1; 
}
```

Also, I think you might want to check whether you're at the last or first position before incrementing or decrementing the Position.

Answer (score 0):

As others have correctly pointed out, you should use **+=** and **-=** operators, which are translated by compiler into addition and assignment expressions:

```
int a = 10;
int b = 20;
a += b;
```

is a shortcut to writing

```
int a = 10;
int b = 20;
a = a + b;
```

However, seeing that you only want to increase and decrease position by one, you may use shorter C-style **++** and **--** operators:

```
private void pictureBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sF1411BindingSource.Position++;
}

private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sF1411BindingSource.Position--;
}
```

This may go a bit off-topic, but I also suggest you to take advantage of C# lambda expressions for event handling. Since you don't do much in the event handlers, you can define them as one-liners in the constructor:

```
public MyForm ()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    nextRecordBox.Click += (sender, e) =>
        bindingSource.Position++;
    prevRecordBox.Click += (sender, e) =>
        bindingSource.Position--;
}
```

These features are only available starting from C# 3.0 but you can use C# 2.0 [anonymous delegates](http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2004/04/05/csharpwhidbeypt1.html) for the same purpose. They save a lot of space from being occupied with one-line methods.

As for the concrete example, I suggest using **MovePrevious** and **MoveNext** methods instead. They are defined in **BindingSource** class too, and are more verbose.

You might also want to jump to the start when user clicks 'Next' on last record.
This is how it would be done:

```
nextRecordBox.Click += (sender, e) => {
        if (bindingSource.Position == bindingSource.Count - 1) // is last
            bindingSource.MoveFirst ();
        else bindingSource.MoveNext ();
    };
```

And, **please**, use good names for UI elements.

Thanks,
Dan